# Allowing directory view/traversal for a specific VirtualHost in Apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, centos6

I have the following vhost configured:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myvhost
    ServerName myv.host.com
    ServerAlias myv.host.com
    ErrorLog logs/myvhost-error_log
    CustomLog logs/myvhost-access_log combined
    ServerAdmin myv@host.com
    <Directory /var/www/myvhost>
        AllowOverride All
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The configuration *appears* to be correct from the `apachectl` tool's perspective.

However, I cannot get a directory listing on that vhost:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

The error log shows the following:

```
[Wed Mar 07 19:23:33 2012] [error] [client 66.6.145.214] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/******
```

#### update2

More recently, the following is now kicking-into the error.log:

```
[Wed Mar 07 20:16:10 2012] [error] [client 192.152.243.233] Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden: /var/www/error/noindex.html
```

#### update3

Today, the following is getting kicked-out:

```
[Thu Mar 08 14:05:56 2012] [error] [client 66.6.145.214] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/<mydir>
[Thu Mar 08 14:05:56 2012] [error] [client 66.6.145.214] Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden: /var/www/error/noindex.html
[Thu Mar 08 14:05:57 2012] [error] [client 66.6.145.214] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

This is after modifying the `vhosts.conf` file thusly:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/<mydir>
    ServerName myhost
    ServerAlias myhost
    ErrorLog logs/myhost-error_log
    CustomLog logs/myhost-access_log combined
    ServerAdmin admin@myhost
    <Directory "/var/www/<mydir>">
         Options All +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What is missing?

### update 4

*All* subdirectories of the root directory do directory listings properly - it is *only* the root which cannot.

Comment: Anything interesting in your error log ? What does your browser display ?

Comment: @Chris S - no mod_index listed in the httpd.conf - nor is there a mod_index on the filesystem

Comment: is there a local `.htaccess` file that might be setting `-Indexes` ?

Comment: @voretaq7 - no .htaccess in this vhost

Comment: @warren Sorry, that should have been mod_autoindex, it's the module that creates directory listing pages.

Comment: @Chris S - that is available and loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### My solution (as of 21 Mar 2012)

- move all content to a subdirectory
- create a redirect `index.html` file in the root that reloads to the subdirectory

I still want to know why I cannot just traverse the directory itself, but this is working for now.

Answer (score 8):

A 403 means the resource is being found. Check that apache has at some level permission to `r-x` the document root and all the directories above it and `r--` the files therein.

Try changing you Directory directive to

```
<Directory /var/www/myvhost>
    AllowOverride All
    Options +Indexes
    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: 775 on the parent dir, and at *least* 644 on all contents

Comment: check it has  suitable r-x perms on /var and /var/www too.

Comment: all other vhosts on this server render properly - which makes this really annoying. Also, even with an 'index.htm' file added, still getting a 403 error

Comment: If the filesystem paths are ok then something else is blocking it try adding 
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
to your vhosts <Directory /var/www/myvhost> definition

Comment: added - and still no dice ... fs perms look completely normal: vhost config looks like all others (except for the directory listing bit).

Comment: @Chris S - found today that it is only affecting the root directory of this vhost

Comment: Just adding a comment, for some one else.. I had the same issue.. I need to add the <Location /> Options Indexes </Location> Directive in the vhost to override the default directive.. This worked for me and I was able to get directory listing for the root as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem today where I was seeing an error like yours shown above:

```
[Wed Oct 17 14:19:08 2012] [error] [client 123.66.66.22] Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden: /var/www/mysite/
```

Mixing options with and without +/- is problematic, note the [apache docs on options](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options):

> Mixing Options with a + or - with those without is not valid syntax,
>   and will be rejected during server startup by the syntax check with an
>   abort.

Also the effect of validly using a directive without a +/- removes all other previously set directives for that directory.

I had used an Indexes without the + and had the error I copied above.

Since you say you are not using any .htaccess files, why not change the Directory directive to this:

```
<Directory /var/www/myvhost>
    AllowOverride None
    Options +Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

On my CentOS 5/6/7 systems this problem is caused by some kind of conflict in the default /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf that comes with the system.  Commenting every line of welcome.conf out and restarting the webserver results in the directory index to be viewable in the webroot.  It appears to simply be a bug in the default webserver configuration that ships out of the box at least on Red Hat/CentOS systems, but potentially others as well.  Your system may have been experiencing a similar issue.